How should this fan and light be wired correctly?
I need to replace a combination switch because I don't think it's wired safely and I think the variable speed control killed the current ceiling fan. The light is a three way switch - a second switch is on the other side of the room. The fan is a single pole controlled by a knob: click to turn turn on, turn to adjust power output. I'd like to replace this with a combination two 3-way toggle switch.
The switch controller has clearly labeled diagrams, which seem straightforward, but I'd really appreciate a sanity check.
I'm also concerned that there's no visible grounding.

Switch diagrams:


And here's how it's wired:



I'd like to replace this with a combination two 3-way toggle switch That will most likely require entirely new cabling from the switch to the fan - or rather from the switch to another switch and from that other switch to the fan. If you just want a simple toggle here for the fan - and 3-way switching only for the light which is already 3-way switched - then that is easy.

Can you post photos of the insides of the other boxes involved please?

it looks like somone may have connected ground an neutral in that box, that's not allowed.

Can you elaborate what your desired end result is? 1. Control the light at two places and the fan at one spot. Fan control is a switch choosing between off and full-on. 2. Control both the light and the fan at two places. Fan control is only off or full-on. 3. Something else.

"If you just want a simple toggle here for the fan - and 3-way switching only for the light which is already 3-way switched - then that is easy."
"1. Control the light at two places and the fan at one spot."
This is what I'm trying to do.

It looks fairly straight-forward, the blue wires (from the switch module) go to the travelers and the red wire goes to the fan motor.
and the black wire goes to the supply.
label those ends before removing the switch module.
replace with a new fan speed controller (or switch if you only want full speed) and a new "3 way" light switch.

Appreciate the response. I'd like to replace this with a combination switch, not a fan speed controller. Would the following work here? https://i.postimg.cc/90DFy7SW/Screenshot-2024-05-13-at-12-16-16-AM.png

@postapollo, yes that would work (assuming you are fine with only having full speed on the fan).
